# hide/show Jquery with datepicker not working

Tags: php, jquery, html, datepicker

I am trying to develop a calendar input variable which also allows for a datepicker for the input boxes.

**HTML**

```
    <select id="select">
  <option value="Type">Type</option>
  <option value="Range">Range</option>
  <option value="Individual">Individual</option>
</select>
<div id="range" style="display:none;">
<input type="text" name="job_from" id="job_from"  placeholder="From" class="datepicker" />
    <input type="text" name="job_to" id="job_to" placeholder="To" class="datepicker" />
</div>

<div id="ind" style="display:none;">

<button type="button" id="add2" class="submit">Add Another Date</button>
    <div id="item2">
        <div><input type="text" class="datepicker" name="jobdates[]" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add2").click(function (e) {
            //Append a new row of code to the "#items" div
            $("#item2").append('<div><input type="text" class="datepicker" name="jobdates[]" /><button class="delete submit" type="button">Delete</button></div>');
        });

    $("body").on("click", ".delete", function (e) {
        $(this).parent("div").remove();
    });

    $('#select').change(function(){
        if($('#select option:selected').text() == "Range"){
        $('#range').show();
        }
        else{
        $('#range').hide();
        }
        if($('#select option:selected').text() == "Individual"){
        $('#ind').show();
        }
        else{
        $('#ind').hide();
        }
    })
});
```

[Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ktzg30Lt/)

when I take away the datepicker jquery function the hide/show functionality works, when i put the datepicker script in nothing works. Can someone explain why I cannot get both to work

Comment: I just added the `jqueryui` scripts as an external resource on jsFiddle and it appears to work fine http://jsfiddle.net/ktzg30Lt/1/

Comment: that is definitely closer, thanks. Other issue is that it only allows the datepicker on the first input in the selection for 'individual' , add the other input and see :(

Comment: hmm I see, give me a min and I will take a look!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is fine, I believe you just weren't including the core jQueryUI files that the DatePicker needs in order to run.

Add this to the `head` of your page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

[EXAMPLE 1](http://jsfiddle.net/ktzg30Lt/1/)

To address the issue where `datepicker` is not being initialized due to the new elements being written to the `DOM` after the `jQuery` has initialized the `datepicker`, you simply must call the `datepicker` when the user creates a new `DOM` element.

```
$("#add2").click(function (e) {
        //Append a new row of code to the "#items" div
        $("#item2").append('<div><input type="text" class="datepicker" name="jobdates[]" /><button class="delete submit" type="button">Delete</button></div>');
        // This is where you need to add the datepicker jQuery again <<<<<<<<<
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({ changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, numberOfMonths: 2, showWeek: true, dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});
});
```

[EXAMPLE 2](http://jsfiddle.net/ktzg30Lt/11/)

Comment: thank you very much, my headache can now simmer away.

Answer (score 0):

I think its not possible.
Make a second input (for datepicker) and show hide it if checked box...
The rest is js and css

EDIT:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$("#add2").click(function (e) {
        //Append a new row of code to the "#items" div
        $("#item2").append('<div><input type="text" class="datepicker" name="jobdates[]"/><button class="delete submit" type="button">Delete</button></div>');
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({ changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, numberOfMonths: 2, showWeek: true, dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});
});

$("body").on("click", ".delete", function (e) {
    $(this).parent("div").remove();
});

$('#select').change(function(){
    if($('#select option:selected').text() == "Range"){
    $('#range').show();
    }
    else{
    $('#range').hide();
    }
    if($('#select option:selected').text() == "Individual"){
    $('#ind').show();
    }
    else{
    $('#ind').hide();
    }
})
});
```

Comment: why is that any different to show hide a DIV with the input datepicker class?